# Zentyal 5: SASL credentials could not be processed

Tags: ldap, samba, sasl, zentyal

I want to ask you for help and point me how i can fix my mistake without reinstalling the whole system.

So...

There was Zentyal 4, and after upgrading to Zentyal 5 I got some errors. 
One of them is:

```
    2017/07/12 17:30:12 INFO> Service.pm:958 EBox::Module::Service::restartService - Restarting service for module: samba
2017/07/12 17:30:27 ERROR> LDAP.pm:196 EBox::Module::LDAP::_connectToSchemaMaster - Error binding to schema master LDAP: The wrong password was supplied or the SASL credentials could not be processed
 at Error binding to schema master LDAP: The wrong password was supplied or the SASL credentials could not be processed
 at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Module/LDAP.pm line 196
EBox::Module::LDAP::_connectToSchemaMaster('EBox::Samba=HASH(0x67ee7e0)') called at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Module/LDAP.pm line 275
EBox::Module::LDAP::_loadSchemasFiles('EBox::Samba=HASH(0x67ee7e0)', 'ARRAY(0x7492840)') called at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Module/LDAP.pm line 267
EBox::Module::LDAP::_loadSchemas('EBox::Samba=HASH(0x67ee7e0)') called at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Module/LDAP.pm line 341
EBox::Module::LDAP::_performSetup('EBox::Samba=HASH(0x67ee7e0)') called at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Samba.pm line 647
EBox::Samba::_regenConfig('EBox::Samba=HASH(0x67ee7e0)', 'restart', 1, 'restartModules', 1) called at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Module/Service.pm line 960
eval {...} at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Module/Service.pm line 959
EBox::Module::Service::restartService('EBox::Samba=HASH(0x67ee7e0)', 'restartModules', 1) called at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Util/Init.pm line 121
eval {...} at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Util/Init.pm line 119
EBox::Util::Init::moduleAction('samba', 'restartService', 'restart') called at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Util/Init.pm line 247
EBox::Util::Init::moduleRestart('samba') called at /usr/bin/zs line 62
main::main at /usr/bin/zs line 82
2017/07/12 17:30:27 ERROR> Service.pm:962 EBox::Module::Service::restartService - Error restarting service: Error binding to schema master LDAP: The wrong password was supplied or the SASL credentials could not be processed
2017/07/12 17:30:27 ERROR> Service.pm:964 EBox::Module::Service::restartService - Error binding to schema master LDAP: The wrong password was supplied or the SASL credentials could not be processed
 at Error binding to schema master LDAP: The wrong password was supplied or the SASL credentials could not be processed
 at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Module/Service.pm line 964
EBox::Module::Service::restartService('EBox::Samba=HASH(0x67ee7e0)', 'restartModules', 1) called at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Util/Init.pm line 121
eval {...} at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Util/Init.pm line 119
EBox::Util::Init::moduleAction('samba', 'restartService', 'restart') called at /usr/share/perl5/EBox/Util/Init.pm line 247
EBox::Util::Init::moduleRestart('samba') called at /usr/bin/zs line 62
main::main at /usr/bin/zs line 82
```

Please, point me where i can update SASL credentials?
And how?

I've asked it on zenytal's forum... but nobody helps (

Answer (score -1):

The error comes from [here](https://github.com/zentyal/zentyal/blob/master/main/samba/src/EBox/Module/LDAP.pm#L196) in the function _connectToSchemaMaster. Apparently the password provided is not correct or maybe the permissions are somewhere wrong and it cannot authenticate.

Comment: getting down-voted .. why?

Comment: maybe, because it is not usefull.

Comment: wow, necrophilia much? ;-) Anyway, is this a domain controller or are you using an external dc? In that case, according to the documentation, you could enter credentials like this: https://wiki.zentyal.org/wiki/En/4.0/Users,_Computers_and_File_Sharing#Configuring_external_Microsoft_Active_Directory.C2.AE. I do not have any experience with this product so I cannot help you any further. Good luck